# DAX expression for sumarizing values to a set date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have done some tests myself but all has been unsuccessful, but if I am missing something please feel free to ask for more information.

I have a spreadsheet with contract numbers on the rows and amortizations on the columns, like the following example:

|  | Original Value | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2105 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2000 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 1002 | 1500 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |
| 1003 | 1200 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 15 | 15 |
| 1004 | 3000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 |

Using DAX is there a good way to make a calculated value for the present value for each of the time frames? As the example below show:

|  | Original Value | PV2101 | PV2102 | PV2103 | PV2114 | PV2105 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 2000 | 1990 | 1980 | 1970 | 1960 | 1950 |
| 1002 | 1500 | 1480 | 1460 | 1440 | 1420 | 1400 |
| 1003 | 1200 | 0 | 0 | 1185 | 1170 | 1155 |
| 1004 | 3000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2990 |

So a calculated value that sums upp all prior amortizations dependant on the date in the x-axis and reduces that amount from the original value.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options:

You create a pivoted table:
|ID  |Year|Value|
|----|----|----|
|1001|2011|  10|
|1001|2012|  10|
|1001|2013|  10|
|1001|2014|  10|
|1001|2015|  10|
|1002|2011|  20|

And then your measure will be trivial:

```
Calculated Value =
  VAR dt_year = YEAR(SELECTED(date[date]))
  RETURN SUM(table[Original Value]) + 
     CALCULATE(SUM(amort[Value]), amort[Year] <= dt_year)
```

Or you create some measure that adds up the individual columns:

```
Calculated Value =
  VAR dt_year = YEAR(SELECTED(date[date]))
  RETURN SUM(table[Original Value]) +
     IF(dt_year >= 2011, SUM(table[2011]), 0) +
     IF(dt_year >= 2012, SUM(table[2012]), 0) +
     IF(dt_year >= 2013, SUM(table[2013]), 0) +
     IF(dt_year >= 2014, SUM(table[2014]), 0) +
     IF(dt_year >= 2015, SUM(table[2015]), 0)
```

Option 1 is a lot nicer.